# How to use Redis as a distributed key value store

Tags: key, redis, distributed

My requirements -

1. Distributed applications sitting on different machines doing set/get operation
2. Ability to add servers and rebalance certain regions of data. [ A.K.A. - consistent hashing ]

Issues -
 Looking through REDIS client which boast of implementing consistent hashing - JEDIS,etc. They seem to be storing the key to shardinfo in memory thereby not sure ahow [1] will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis does not have really distributed solution, Redis Cluster is on its way yet. You can do [master-slave replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication) to afford higher performance and reliability. But all stuff like "automatically select new master if old master is offline" should be done manually.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://antirez.com/post/redis-presharding.html) blog post from the author of redis might be helpful. As stated there, for the moment you can shard on the client, which suffers from maintainability problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another example illustrating [REDIS sharding at CRAIGLIST](http://blog.zawodny.com/2011/02/26/redis-sharding-at-craigslist/) wherein they have virtual node names on the consistent hash ring and can double the capacity without re-sharding/shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

Redis Cluster implementation is in progress and also under beta Testing. However it's not stable right now but you can try it. 
http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

There is another option also Sharded Jedis Pool. 
https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage